# Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor : javax.script.ScriptException

Tags: jmeter, scripting-language, jsr223

I am using Jmeter 5.0 where i have piece of java code written inside a JSR223 PostProcessor. The code is as follows -

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;


Map gamePlayHistoryMap = new HashMap();
gamePlayHistoryMap.put(${playerId}, ${GameplayHistoryId});
props.put("GamePlayHistoryMap", gamePlayHistoryMap);

Map payLevelDetailsMap = new HashMap();
payLevelDetailsMap.put(${playerId}, ${PayLevelDetails});
props.put("PayLevelDetailsMap", payLevelDetailsMap);
```

However when i execute the test plan, in the console i get the following error -

> javax.script.ScriptException: In file: inline evaluation of: `import java.util.Map; import java.util.HashMap;   Map gamePlayHistoryMap = new H . . . '' Encountered "( 107 , )" at line 6, column 23.
>    in inline evaluation of:`import java.util.Map; import java.util.HashMap;   Map gamePlayHistoryMap = new H . . . '' at line number 6

Can someone help me in pointing where i might have gone wrong ?

Comment: ${playerId}, ${GameplayHistoryId}, ${PayLevelDetails} - These values i am extracting using JSONExtractor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `${}` in JSR223 scripts, use instead `vars.get("")` to get varibles

```
gamePlayHistoryMap.put(vars.get("playerId"), vars.get("GameplayHistoryId"));
```

It seems that `GameplayHistoryId` is empty, in such case add default value in `JSONExtractor` or fail test

See JMeter's best practices for [JSR223](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) scripting:

> In this case, ensure the script does not use any variable using `${varName}` as caching would take only first value of `${varName}`. Instead use :
>   `vars.get("varName")`

Comment: Don't use ${} in JSR223 scripts, use instead vars.get("") to get varibles - why ?

Comment: @AritroSen see JMeter's best practices for JSR223: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223

Comment: Okay. 1 More Question - I have like 3 JsonExtractor in a single thread. How do i use the value extracted in the first to the third ?

Comment: @AritroSen Please ask a new question with relevant details and example

Comment: I understood the JSR223 scripting part. How do i use the props to extract the values of this map in my subsequent thread - I have coded like this -
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;


Map gameTemplateIdMap = props.get("GamePlayHistoryMap");
Map payLevelDetailsMap = props.get("PayLevelDetailsMap");

is this correct way ?

Comment: @AritroSen for supporting different thread you will have to update JMeter property as `props.put`, but you should ask another specific question for specific answer

Answer (score 1):

1. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), looking into your exception details it appears you're using `java` which is not real Java, it's [Beanshell interpreter](http://www.beanshell.org/) which has [worse performance comparing to Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) and you have to stick to Java 5 syntax.
2. Don't inline [JMeter Functions and/or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into scripts as they might be resolved into something causing script failures and in case of Groovy they conflict with GString templates and compilation caching feature. Use `vars` shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class to read existing variables values and create new ones, i.e. replace this line:

   ```
   gamePlayHistoryMap.put(${playerId}, ${GameplayHistoryId});
   ```

   with this one:

   ```
   gamePlayHistoryMap.put(vars.get('playerId'), vars.get('GameplayHistoryId'));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the Map key/value definition.

```
Map <String, String> gamePlayHistoryMap = new HashMap<>();
gamePlayHistoryMap.put(${playerId}, ${GameplayHistoryId});
```

Not sure about the answer of:

> Don't use ${} in JSR223 scripts, use instead vars.get("")

not sure it has anything to do with it.