# JMeter Compilable JSR223 Usage Precautions

Tags: variables, caching, groovy, jmeter, jsr223

Update - TL'DR:

When it comes to the *compilable* and *cacheable* JSR223 Elements, I've saw people using all sorts of tactics dancing around it. I had my doubts and I had my answers here, and found that most of tactics I saw are done wrong:

- If your JSR223 scripts are full of `args[0]`, `args[1]`, `args[2]` everywhere, then that's the wrong choice of tactic, even it is the best practice of JMeter, it is not the best practice in the software engineering and easy-maintenance point of view.
- Even if you assign `args[n]` to some meaningful-named variables, it is not the best practice in JMeter either, as there are much simpler and straightforward ways.
- Similarly, if you are following the [advices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54978017/2125837) of *"using `vars.get("")` to get variables"* (then assign them to some meaningful-named variables), it is not the best practice in JMeter either, as there are much simpler and straightforward ways.
- The [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54978017/2125837) of *"Don't use `${}` in JSR223 scripts"* is more a myth than the truth, as all the `${}` using examples in this question are just fine.
- Also, the [advices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58342550/2125837) of breaking up expressions like `"ValidAssetIds_${i+1}_g"` with "`+`" into `"ValidCatalogAssetIds_"+ (i+1) + "_g"` is just another myth, and in most cases untruth, as illustrated in this question.

Now, as per [JMeter's best practices for JSR223](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223):

The reason JSR223 Elements is recommended for intensive load testing over Beanshell or Javascript, is because it implements the ***Compilable*** interface, as Groovy scripting engine implements Compilable.

And, it tells people to

> ***ensure***
>
> - to check (enable) the `Cache compiled script if available` property to ensure the script compilation is cached
> - the script does not use any variable using `${varName}` as caching would take only first value of ${varName}. Instead use:
>   `vars.get("varName")`,

like:

[image]

Else, the other option is to pass them as `Parameters` to the script, like this:

[image]

Now, my question are,

1. What would happen if I use

   ```
    def my_var = vars.get("MY_VARIABLE")
    log.info("The value of my_var is ${my_var}")
   ```

in above example? Would log changes in each iteration when `MY_VARIABLE` changes?

2. Instead of above, I also tried to use

   ```
    def my_var2 = __V(MY_VARIABLE)
    def my_var3 = ${__V(MY_VARIABLE)}
   ```

but somehow I wasn't able to get the values of `MY_VARIABLE`. What I'm missing?

3. what if my `${varName}` is dynamically defined, what would happen if I use `${varName}` in such form? Like,

case 1:

```
for(def i = 0; i < validAssets.size(); i++) {
    vars.put("ValidAssetIds_${i+1}_v","${i+1}")
}
```

case 2:

```
def varName = ${__time(/1000,)}
vars.put("MY_Log","abc${varName}")
```

Would each iteration have their own `MY_Log` values, or they all will be the same? I know I can guess my conclusion from observations, but the purpose of this question is to let me (or people) know the precautions when it comes to using JSR223 that we might not be aware of before. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All the "precautions" are described in the [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

> When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as **caching would only cache first replacement**. Instead use script parameters.

For example if you define a [random string](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) via [User Parameters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters):

[image]

and try to refer it as `${randomString}` in Groovy - it will be "random" only during the first iteration, on subsequent iterations the "first" value will be used:

[image]

1. Questions 1 and 3 are using Groovy's [string interpolation feature](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation), it's safe to use unless there is a clash with other JMeter Variables names
2. Question 2: you need to surround the [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) with quotation marks otherwise the variable value is resolved but it's not defined in Groovy causing compilation error, you should see a message in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) regarding it

   ```
   def my_var2 = "${__V(MY_VARIABLE,)}"
   ```

Check out [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter context.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri! As you can see, all my questions are around, _"ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code"_, and from your previous answer, _"it's not recommended to inline JMeter Functions or Variables into JSR223 scripts"_, because I'm not too familiar with JMeter, not Groovy, so I'm having difficulties understanding what they exactly mean. The "best practice" made it more clearer by saying _"does not use any variable using ${varName}"_, however, as you can see from my Questions 1 and 3, it is not 100% true. Just like my follow up Q